# WebView.loadData not working on Android 9.0 (API-29)

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, android-9.0-pie

I have an article app, I am showing articles in `WebView`. In Android version 9.0 (API-29) this `WebView` is not working. The app shows **NOTHING** in my article Activity.

```
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setMinimumFontSize(14);

String htmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
   + "<head>"
   + "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"
   + "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/>"
   + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #525252;} img {max-width: 100%; height: auto}</style>"
   + "</head>"
   + item.getContent() //content of item
   + "";

mWebView.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

As a result, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I solved my problem, the problem occurs in Smartphones that has latest Chrome.

**SOLUTION:**

Do not use

`mWebview.loadData`

method, instead **use**

`mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL`

As a result my solution is:

`mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlContent,"text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Comment: The weird part is, loadData is working with debug build. It only cease to work on release build.

Comment: @neobie any chance you resolved issue with release build? In my case both `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseUrl` not working with any parameters in release build, only in debug build. And it's also specific for project, cause test project created from scratch show local content with webView in release build perfectly fine.

Comment: I included the baseUrl (the url where I originally got the html from) instead of keeping it null. My guess is that the problem was, that whenever the webview tried to get images for the html then he wouldn't know where to look but after I gave it the original url then it knew where to find them

Answer (score 39):

Your HTML content should be either Base64 or URL encoded. Your HTML example has a "#" in it, and it causes the problem on some WebView versions.

Here's an example with Base64 encoding.

```
String htmlContent = "...";
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(htmlContent.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);
webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

Here's [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for detail.

Comment: Saved my life bro!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.  Thank you sir.

Comment: Great! This should be the accepted answer, my web view stoped to work when I upgraded to 29 from 28, you save my day! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

I too had the same problem with Android Version 9.0

The documents at this page (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration) mention that:

> In Android 9, the UTF-8 decoder for Java language is stricter and
>   follows the Unicode standard.

So I tried converting the UTF-8 into Base64 and use loadData()

```
try {
       String base64 = null;
       base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(lecureHtmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
       wvLecture.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now it is working as usual.

Hope it helps